# Zip directory with subdirectories in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

Working with Robot Framework, I'm trying to zip a directory with one files and three subdirectories containing files. I'm using the [ArchiveLibrary](http://bulkan.github.io/robotframework-archivelibrary) and the keyword Create Zip From Files In Directory. The result is a zipped directory containing the one file in the top directory and three empty subfolders.

**How can I adjust the library so that also the subfolder's content is included?**

This is how the keyword is originally defined:

```
def create_zip_from_files_in_directory(self, directory, filename):

    ''' Take all files in a directory and create a zip package from them
    `directory` Path to the directory that holds our files
    `filename` Path to our destination ZIP package.
    '''

    if not directory.endswith("/"):
        directory = directory + "/"
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, "w")
    files = os.listdir(directory)
    for name in files:
        zip.write(directory + name, arcname=name)
    zip.close()
```

[Link](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-archivelibrary/blob/master/ArchiveLibrary/keywords.py) to the complete library.

I've been experimenting with os.walk, without success.

How the keyword is used in the .robot file:

```
Zip xml file
    ${zipfilename}=    set variable    komplett.zip
    Create zip from Files in directory    ../xml/komplett/  ${zipfilename}
```

*If it makes a difference, I really only need to solve this specific case, not a general one, meaning that I don't mind typing in paths to each directory and then join that somehow, I just don't understand how to do it... 
Also, I use PyCharm as editor, not RIDE.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: when using the library version 0.4 and up, you can choose whether subdirectories should be included. E.g.:

```
Create Zip From Files In Directory    ../xml/komplett/  no_sub_folders.zip
Create Zip From Files In Directory    ../xml/komplett/  dir_and_sub_folders.zip   sub_directories=${true}
```

The keyword for creating tar is a bit different - by default it includes the files in subdirectories, and now you have an option not to:

```
Create Tar From Files In Directory    ../xml/komplett/  dir_and_sub_folders.tar 
Create Tar From Files In Directory    ../xml/komplett/  no_sub_folders.tar   sub_directories=${false}
```

The default values of `sub_directories` are based on the preexisting behavior, not to break exisiting usages in test cases.

---

Original answer, for versions < 0.4:

If you're willing to patch the library, this code should do:

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, "w")
for path, _, files in os.walk(directory):
    for name in files:
        file_to_archive = os.path.join(path, name)

        # get rid of the starting directory - so the zip structure is top-level starting from it
        file_name = path.replace(directory, '')
        file_name = os.path.join(file_name, name)

        zip.write(file_to_archive, arcname=file_name) # set the desired name in the archive by the arcname argument
zip.close()
```

Edit: preserves the sub-directory structure for files in - subdirectories.
The generated file is with top-level the target directory, and all its subdirectories - beneath it (as opposed to the archive preserving the full path to the target directory)

The `arcname` [argument controls](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) what is the name of a file stored in the archive - and through line 7, we are preserving the relative directory plus the file name.

Always use `os.path.join` cause it automatically takes care of differences in the different file systems (ntfs/linux/etc).

If the final solution works for you, don't forget to propose a patch to the library owner - give back to the community :)

Comment: Thanks! This landed me a bit closer, but didn't work exactly as hoped. Now I get all files, but instead the subdirectories are removed. 
To make the robot-script work, I need to keep the exact structure of the directory (OT: because the actual test is running the zipped directory through a validation script, where the test variation is to change data in an xml file that is placed in the zipped directory)
Can the subdirectories and structure also be included?

Comment: Well, "that'll teach me to post w/o running" :) JK, edited the answer to include that part also - plus cleaned up some code that wasn't really needed. HTH

Comment: Wonderful, just what I wanted! Thanks! :)

Comment: The PR is in, keep fingers crossed it makes it to a next release of the library :)

Comment: @Todor library auther here; thanks for the PR I've commented on it.